# Communication between 2 Classes

Tags: java

I'm a newbie java programer and I'm trying to make my first project.

I need to pass a variable between 2 classes, which is going fine. The problem is that the variable has a changing value and i cannot pass the actual value. Here is an example:

```
public class A{
    private int counter = 0;

    public int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }

    //here some code which will increase or decrease the value of the counter variable 
    //lets say for the sake of the example that at this point the value of the variable is 1.
    //counter = 1;
}

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());// here I need the actual counter variable value which is currently: 1
    }
}
```

My problem is that i always receive 0. How can i pass the actual value of the variable.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can pass values to the constructor of another class

Comment: You should show your full code, including the parts that change `counter`. What you have posted will give exactly the result you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make variable static so that it will be associated with class.

```
public class A{
   private static int counter = 0;

   public int getCounter(){
      counter++;
      return counter;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A a = new A();
```

After instantiation (above statement) you need to call the method which will increment the counter here.

Example:

```
   a.incrementCounter();
```

Then below statement will get counter value.

```
 System.out.println(a.getCounter());
```

Answer (score 1):

> lets say for the sake of the example that at this point the value of the variable is 1.

No, by the time that code is read, the value did not change. All you do inside a `class`-block is to define a class, the “template” for an object. At that time, no values are set though.

The `a.getCounter()` you use already does the correct job: It returns the *current* value of `a`’s counter variable. If it does not return 1, then obviously the value hasn’t changed yet.

```
public class A {
    private int counter = 0;
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void increaseCounter() {
        counter++;
    }
}

public class B {
    public static void main() {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());
        a.increaseCounter();
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.setCounter(5);
        System.out.println(a.getCounter()); 
    }


public class A{
    private int counter = 0;

    public int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }



      public void setCounter(int count ){
            this.counter=count;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use constructors/setter...

```
public class A{
    private int counter = 0;

    public A(int c){
        counter = c
    }

    public int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int c){
        counter = c;
    }

    public void incCounter(){
        counter++;
    }
}

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(123);
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());

        a.setCounter(456);
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());

        a.incCounter();
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {

    private int counter = 0;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public int increment() {//////////create increment Method which will increase the counter , or do any function you want
        return counter++;
    }

    public void  setCounter(int c) {///////////this method will allow you to set the counter
        counter=c;
     }
  }

class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.increment();///////if you call this function will change your counter , if not , you will get it = 0
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());
    }
}
```

---

```
A a = new A();
System.out.println(a.getCounter());
```

**The Output** = 0

```
A a = new A();
a.increment();
System.out.println(a.getCounter());
```

**The Output** =1

```
 a = new A();
 a.setCounter(10);//////////here you set the `counter`  by 10
 System.out.println(a.getCounter());
```

**The Output** =10;

Answer (score 0):

You have one class (Counter) which manages the counter int variable.

You would like for one or more other classes to be able to increment and/or get the counter value.

In that case, each instance of those classes should have a reference to the **same instance** of Counter (stored as member variable, passed to their constructor or a setter method).

```
class Counter {
    private int counter = 0;
    public int getValue() { return counter; }
    public void increment() { counter++; }
    public String toString() { return Integer.toString(counter); }
}

class CounterUser {
    private final Counter counter;
    public CounterUser(Counter counter) { this.counter = counter; }
    public String toString() { return Integer.toString(counter.getValue()); }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        CounterUser a = new CounterUser(counter);
        CounterUser b = new CounterUser(counter);
        System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", counter, a, b);
        counter.increment();
        System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", counter, a, b);
        b.increment();
        System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", counter, a, b);     }
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the constructor and/or create method that changes the value.

```
public class A
{
    private int counter = 0;

    public A()
    {
        // value is set first time you create an instance of A. (e.g when you do A a = new A();
        counter = 1;
    }

    public int getCounter()
    {
        return counter;
    }

    public void incrementCounter()
    {
        counter++;
    }

}

public class B
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());// Output : 1
        a.incrementCounter();
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());// Output : 2

        a.incrementCounter();
        a.incrementCounter();
        a.incrementCounter();
        System.out.println(a.getCounter());// Output : 5
    }
}
```